# Initialize Room Database in Activity or Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-room

I am in the process of transitioning an android app from a primitive, single activity to a more robust app using fragments to allow for better performance. 
Part of this is moving to the Room model. Now I am still trying to understand how a room database is implemented which is where my question comes from.

Basically what I am asking is: if I am using fragments to display separate data sets from the same database, do I make the initialization of the database in the activity and then call that database from the fragment? 
I am assuming that the mainactivity will need to house the database so that it is consolidated among all of the fragments rather than each fragment building its own database. Or does it not matter?

Answer (score 0):

From [Room documentations](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room):

```
AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
    AppDatabase.class, "database-name").build();
```

> Note: If your app runs in a single process, you should follow the singleton design pattern when instantiating an AppDatabase object. Each RoomDatabase instance is fairly expensive, and you rarely need access to multiple instances within a single process.